# Quando usar listas e quando usar tuplas?

Tags: python, tipagem

Qual é a diferença entre os tipos `list` e `tuple` no Python e quando devo usar cada um?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ambas são tipos de sequências de dados, mas uma é **mutável** e a outra **imutável**. Tanto lista como tupla são sequências de dados e possuem muitas propriedades comuns, mas a diferença básica é que a lista é mutável e a tupla é imutável.

#### O que é imutável?

Conforme o [glossário](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-immutable) da documentação da linguagem Python, imutável refere-se a um objeto com valor fixo. Objetos imutáveis incluem strings, números e tuplas. Caso seja necessário alterar o valor de um objeto imutável, outro objeto deve ser criado a fim de armazená-lo.  Eles desempenham um papel importante em locais onde um valor de *hash* constante é necessário, por exemplo como uma chave em um dicionário.

Na prática, isso implica em que não é possível fazer atribuições à um objeto imutável. Para uma lista, como o exemplo abaixo, é possível alterá-la através de uma operação de atribuição:

```
>>> lista = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> print(lista)
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> lista[0] = 9
>>> print(lista)
[9, 1, 2, 3]
```

Porém, repetir o exemplo utilizando uma tupla:

```
>>> tupla = (0, 1, 2, 3)
>>> print(tupla)
(0, 1, 2, 3)
>>> tupla[0] = 9
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Um erro é disparado ao se tentar fazer uma atribuição a um objeto do tipo tupla.

#### Operações comuns às listas e tuplas

As operações listadas abaixo funcionam para `s` e `t` sendo tanto listas como tuplas.

[image: Operações comuns às sequências]
<sub>Fonte: [Built-In Types: Common Sequence Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)</sub>

#### E qual a diferença?

A única operação que tipos imutáveis implementam que os tipos mutáveis não suportam é a função [`hash()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash). Isto permite a tipos imutáveis, tal como a tupla, serem utilizados como chaves de dicionários e armazenadas em [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) e [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset).

Portanto, é possível fazer:

```
>>> d = {
...     (1, 2): "Stack Overflow em Português"
... }
>>> print(d)
{(1, 2): 'Stack Overflow em Português'}
```

Pois, em memória, a chave do dicionário é relacionada ao valor *hash* da tupla. Sendo uma lista um tipo mutável, fazer o mesmo resulta em um erro indicando que a lista não suporta *hash*.

```
>>> d = {
...     [1, 2]: "Stack Overflow em Português"
... }
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

#### Cuidados

Embora a tupla seja um tipo imutável, se possuir um valor de um tipo mutável, o mesmo permanece mutável enquanto dentro da tupla. Por exemplo, se considerarmos uma tupla de listas:

```
>>> tupla = ([1, 2], [3, 4])
```

É possível alterar os valores da lista:

```
>>> tupla[0][0] = 9
>>> print(tupla)
([9, 2], [3, 4])
```

Ou mesmo chamar os métodos nativos do tipo do objeto, tal como `append`:

```
>>> tupla[1].append(0)
>>> print(tupla)
([9, 2], [3, 4, 0)
```

Embora isso seja possível, o objeto, mesmo do tipo tupla, perde a propriedade de ser um tipo imutável e, portanto, deixa de ser um objeto *hashable*. Ao tentar fazer, considerando `tupla` do exemplo anterior:

```
>>> hash(tupla)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Um erro será disparado indicando que a tupla possui valores que são mutáveis e, portanto, impossível de calcular o *hash*.

#### Quando se utiliza listas?

As listas são sequências mutáveis, **tipicamente** usadas para armazenar coleções de itens homogêneos (onde o grau preciso de similaridade variará conforme a aplicação).

Isto é, se uma lista contém valores inteiros, espera-se que sejam apenas valores inteiros. Dificilmente você terá uma lista armazenando valores de tipos distintos, tal como `[1, "Foo", True]`.

<sub>Fonte: [Built-In Types: Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists)</sub>

#### Quando se utiliza tuplas?

As tuplas são sequências imutáveis, **normalmente** usadas para armazenar coleções de dados heterogêneos (como a tupla produzida pela função `enumerate` nativa). As tuplas também são usadas para casos onde uma sequência imutável de dados homogêneos é necessária (como permitir o armazenamento em `set` ou `dict`).

As tuplas podem possuir valores de tipos diferentes, onde cada um representa algo específico. Como o próprio retorno da função `enumerate` de uma lista, o retorno será uma tupla de dois valores, em que o primeiro representa o índice do valor na lista e o segundo o valor propriamente dito.

```
>>> lista = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> print(list(enumerate(lista)))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

Ou seja, um valor da tupla é do tipo inteiro, enquanto o outro é do tipo string.

<sub>Fonte: [Built-In Types: Tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples)</sub>

#### Tuplas nomeadas

Caso ainda queira utilizar das propriedades da tupla, mas deseja acessar seus valores através de índices nomeados, pode utilizar a estrutura [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

```
>>> import collections
>>> Person = collections.namedtuple('Person', 'name age gender')
>>> foo = Person(name="Foo", age=30, gender="male")
>>> print(foo)
Person(name='Foo', age=30, gender='male')
>>> print(hash(foo))
2739343292757077799
```

Perceba que mesmo sendo uma tupla nomeada, utilizar a função `hash` ainda é possível (desde que os valores sejam todos de tipos imutáveis).