# Retirar espaços de índices em uma lista

Tags: python, lista

Na lista abaixo, eu quero imprimir somente o gênero de cada índice, o que, de fato, consigo, mas como vocês podem notar existem 4 listas que estão sem definição de gênero, o que ocasiona, na hora de imprimir vários espaços. Eu gostaria de imprimir os gêneros de uma forma mais organizada, formatando o texto. Vejam como ficou minha saída abaixo no exemplo.

```
['2017-01-01 00:02:54', '2017-01-01 00:08:21', '327', 'Larrabee St & Menomonee St', 'Sheffield Ave & Kingsbury St', 'Subscriber', 'Male', '1984.0']
['2017-01-01 00:06:06', '2017-01-01 00:18:31', '745', 'Orleans St & Chestnut St (NEXT Apts)', 'Ashland Ave & Blackhawk St', 'Subscriber', 'Male', '1985.0']
['2017-01-01 00:07:28', '2017-01-01 00:12:51', '323', 'Franklin St & Monroe St', 'Clinton St & Tilden St', 'Subscriber', 'Male', '1990.0']
['2017-01-01 00:07:57', '2017-01-01 00:20:53', '776', 'Broadway & Barry Ave', 'Sedgwick St & North Ave', 'Subscriber', 'Male', '1990.0']
['2017-01-01 00:10:44', '2017-01-01 00:21:27', '643', 'State St & Kinzie St', 'Wells St & Polk St', 'Subscriber', 'Male', '1970.0']
['2017-01-01 00:11:34', '2017-01-01 00:23:47', '733', 'Wabash Ave & Wacker Pl', 'Clinton St & Tilden St', 'Subscriber', 'Male', '1986.0']
['2017-01-01 00:14:57', '2017-01-01 00:26:22', '685', 'Daley Center Plaza', 'Canal St & Monroe St (*)', 'Customer', '', '']
['2017-01-01 00:15:03', '2017-01-01 00:26:28', '685', 'Daley Center Plaza', 'Canal St & Monroe St (*)', 'Customer', '', '']
['2017-01-01 00:17:01', '2017-01-01 00:29:49', '768', 'Dayton St & North Ave', 'Ogden Ave & Chicago Ave', 'Customer', '', '']
['2017-01-01 00:17:13', '2017-01-01 11:03:34', '38781', 'Wilton Ave & Diversey Pkwy', 'Halsted St & Wrightwood Ave', 'Subscriber', 'Female', '1988.0']
['2017-01-01 00:18:28', '2017-01-01 00:31:05', '757', 'Canal St & Madison St', 'LaSalle St & Illinois St', 'Customer', '', '']
['2017-01-01 00:18:50', '2017-01-01 00:21:47', '177', 'Theater on the Lake', 'Lakeview Ave & Fullerton Pkwy', 'Subscriber', 'Male', '1991.0']
['2017-01-01 00:23:41', '2017-01-01 00:29:13', '332', 'Halsted St & Maxwell St', 'Halsted St & 18th St', 'Subscriber', 'Male', '1984.0']
['2017-01-01 00:25:47', '2017-01-01 00:39:53', '846', 'Ravenswood Ave & Lawrence Ave', 'Clarendon Ave & Gordon Ter', 'Subscriber', 'Female', '1987.0']
['2017-01-01 00:25:47', '2017-01-01 00:43:23', '1056', 'Clark St & Congress Pkwy', 'Wolcott Ave & Polk St', 'Subscriber', 'Male', '1984.0']
['2017-01-01 00:26:21', '2017-01-01 00:39:40', '799', 'Ravenswood Ave & Lawrence Ave', 'Clarendon Ave & Gordon Ter', 'Subscriber', 'Male', '1987.0']
['2017-01-01 00:27:21', '2017-01-01 00:42:59', '938', 'Millennium Park', 'Michigan Ave & 18th St', 'Subscriber', 'Male', '1991.0']
['2017-01-01 00:27:28', '2017-01-01 00:42:44', '916', 'Millennium Park', 'Michigan Ave & 18th St', 'Subscriber', 'Female', '1990.0']
['2017-01-01 00:27:45', '2017-01-01 00:31:13', '208', 'Damen Ave & Chicago Ave', 'Damen Ave & Division St', 'Subscriber', 'Male', '1982.0']
['2017-01-01 00:27:52', '2017-01-01 00:33:46', '354', 'Paulina Ave & North Ave', 'Damen Ave & Division St', 'Subscriber', 'Female', '1982.0']
```

Minha saída ficou assim:

```
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male
Male



Female

Male
Male
Female
Male
Male
Male
Female
Male
Female
```

Comment: "forma mais organizada"? O que é isso? Podes dar um exemplo do que pretendes pff? Qual o código que tens?

Comment: sem os espaços , @Miguel , note que eu imprimi os gêneros , mas como é um projeto eu queria deixar o texto mais formatado , entende?

Comment: for i in range(len(data_list[2:22])):
    print(data_list[i],[6]) , usei este código , o loop for para acessar as linhas e os índices .

Comment: Será isto: https://repl.it/repls/ThistleSereneGeeklog

Comment: obrigado , irei testar , mas o que seria essa exclamação ? eu já tinha visto ela mas esqueci o significado .

Comment: Qual interrogação? Não estou a perceber

Comment: Acho que seria exclamação, está a fazer da negação penso eu.

Comment: sim sim , exclamação. entendi agora.

Comment: `!=` significa 'diferente de', o oposto de `==`, 'igual a'.

Comment: @Miguel, obrigado novamente. irei testar o código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode definir um gerador que pegará os gêneros não nulos de seus dados, depois iterá-lo, imprimindo o resultado. Por exemplo:

```
genres = (columns[6] for columns in data if columns[6])

for genre in genres:
    print(genre)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/SaltyShorttermCore) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/KQIFSp) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/b26e73c0000db9151ef9861e3ce9e70b)</sup>

Se essas listas representam um conjunto de dados relacionados, o que parece ser, recomendo fortemente que pesquise sobre `NamedTuple`.

[Quando usar listas e quando usar tuplas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192727/5878)

Comment: Nice, python nunca para de me surpreender!