# Um cadastro de pessoas em python

Tags: python

Estava querendo fazer um cadastro de pessoa com `id`, `nome` e `idade`, criei esse código. O problema está na opção 2, quando mostrar. Eu queria mostrar assim:

```
print("nome",nome_pessoa,"idade",idade_pessoa,"id",id_pessoa)
```

porém da forma que está eu não consigo controlar da forma que citei acima.

Alguém sabe como resolver ou se existe uma forma melhor de fazer esse cadastro? Queria também saber se tem como mostra os dados de uma pessoa em específico como pede a opção 3

```
listas = [[]] #uma lista de lista

while True:
    print("1-Cadastrar pessoa")
    print("2-Lista Cadastros")
    print("3-Procurar Pessoa Especifica")
    op = int(input())#Escolha da opcao
    if op == 1:
        nova = [] # cria uma lista para adicionar o id, nome e idade da pessoa
        id = input("Id da pessoa")
        nome = input("Digite o nome da pessoa")
        idade = input("Idade da pessoa")
        nova.append(id)
        nova.append(nome)
        nova.append(idade)
        listas.append(nova)#Adiciona a lista criada com o cadastro da pessoa dentro da lista

    elif op == 2:
        for mostrar in listas:
            for mostrar2 in mostrar:
                print(mostrar2)#mostra tudo dentro da

    elif op == 3:
        print("pensando")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opção 2:
Para formatar prints você pode fazer assim:

```
elif op == 2:
    for mostrar in listas:
        try:
            print("Nome: %s - Idade: %s - ID: %s"%(mostrar[1],mostrar[2],mostrar[0]))
        except:
            print("Essa pessoa não possui algum dos valores a seguir: Nome, Idade, ID")
```

Se o valor de uma das variáveis for um inteiro, você troca o %s por %d, caso seja um float, deve trocar %s por %f.

Opção 3:

```
id = input("Digite o id da pessoa desejada: ")
for mostrar in listas:
    if id in mostrar:
        try:
            print("Nome: %s - Idade: %s - ID: %s"%(mostrar[1],mostrar[2],mostrar[0]))
        except:
            print("Essa pessoa não possui algum dos valores a seguir: Nome, Idade, ID")
```

Comment: ta dando esse erro

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nathan/PycharmProjects/Aula/Aula.py", line 19, in <module>
    print("Id: %s, Nome: %s, Idade: %s"%(mostrar[0],mostrar[1],mostrar[2]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: eu fiz uns cadastro e printei a lista. Saida: [[], ['1', 'aaa', '1'], ['2', 'bbb', '2']]

Comment: tudo bem amigo.

Comment: muito obrigado amigo, outra pergunta, como faria pra tirar esse vazio?

Comment: muito obrigado, consegui!

Comment: uma duvida. A solução do 2 não da certo.

Comment: Editado, tente novamente

Answer (score 4):

Acredito que o problema tenha sido resolvido nas outras respostas, mas deixarei aqui uma sugestão de como eu resolveria o problema, caso tenha interesse de estudar uma alternativa.

Primeiro, você tem 4 tarefas bem definidas no seu projeto:

1. Exibir o menu;
2. Opção 1, de cadastrar uma pessoa;
3. Opção 2, de listar as pessoas cadastradas;
4. Opção 3, de procurar os dados de uma pessoa;

Por quê, então, não criar uma função para cada?

**Exibindo o menu...**

```
def exibir_menu():
    print('''Escolha uma opção:

    1. Cadastrar uma pessoa
    2. Listar pessoas cadastradas
    3. Procurar dados de uma pessoa
    ''')
```

**Cadastrando uma pessoa...**

```
def cadastrar(pessoas):
    identificador = input('Id? ')
    nome = input('Nome? ')
    idade = int(input('Idade? '))
    pessoas.append((identificador, nome, idade))
```

As considerações seriam:

- Não utilizar um objeto chamado `id`, pois é o nome de uma função nativa do Python;
- O valor de `idade` é convertido para inteiro, pois é um número - isso facilitará em caso de necessitar ordenar a lista pela idade;
- Foi criado uma tupla com os dados - note a presença de dois parenteses no `append`;

A utilização da tupla segue a mesma lógica que você utilizou com a lista, para guardar os valores agrupados, porém com tupla o código fica mais semântico.

[Quando usar listas e quando usar tuplas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192727/5878)

**Listando as pessoas...**

```
def listar(pessoas):
    for pessoa in pessoas:
        identificador, nome, idade = pessoa
        print(f'Nome: {nome}, idade: {idade}, id: {identificador}')
```

Aqui, utilizo a desconstrução de tupla para passar a tupla `pessoa`, que possui as três informações da pessoa, para três variáveis distintas; assim, o código ficará muito mais legível, pois é mais fácil entender que `nome` é o nome da pessoa a que `pessoa[1]`. E para exibir as informações, utilizei as *f-strings*, do Python 3.6 - onde, por exemplo, `{nome}` será substituído pelo valor de `nome`.

**Buscando uma pessoa...**

```
def buscar(pessoas):
    identificador_desejado = input('Id? ')
    for pessoa in pessoas:
        identificador, nome, idade = pessoa
        if identificador == identificador_desejado:
            print(f'Nome: {nome}, idade: {idade}, id: {identificador}')
            break
    else:
        print(f'Pessoa com id {identificador_desejado} não encontrada')
```

Que, basicamente, percorre a lista de pessoas em busca do id desejado e, quando achar, exibe as informações da pessoa, caso contrário é exibida a mensagem que a pessoa não foi encontrada.

**Juntando tudo...**

Assim, o código ficaria algo como:

```
def main():
    pessoas = []

    while True:
        exibir_menu()
        opcao = int(input('Opção? '))
        if opcao == 1:
            cadastrar(pessoas)
        elif opcao == 2:
            listar(pessoas)
        elif opcao == 3:
            buscar(pessoas)
        else:
            print('Opção inválida')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/NeatCriminalSale)</sup>

O que já melhora bastante a legibilidade do código e facilita a manutenção do projeto. Mesmo assim, é importante salientar que muita coisa poderia ser melhorada; por exemplo, a leitura dos dados está sendo realizada dentro da função, junto com a lógica de cadastrar - ou seja, são duas responsabilidades para a mesma função, isso nem sempre é bom fazer, pois impossibilita você de utilizar a função em outros lugares (e se eu quiser cadastrar uma pessoa que já sei os dados? Teria que criar outra função, duplicando a lógica de cadastro, o que fere os princípios de DRY).

A mesma coisa acontece com as outras funções, por exemplo. E se eu quiser enviar a lista completa por e-mail ao invés de exibir na tela? Precisaria uma função diferente da `listar` que teria uma lógica bastante semelhante.

Outra alteração trivial a ser feita que melhoraria bastante a legibilidade do código seria utilizar `namedtuple`, ao invés de apenas tuplas, dispensando, assim, a *necessidade* de fazer a desconstrução da tupla para variáveis.

Dito isso, deixo em aberto essas melhorias para, caso você, ou quem estiver lendo, buscar por conta própria elaborar tais melhorias no código e, se o fizer, que poste como resposta aqui, pois será útil para muitos usuários.

Comment: acho que eu entendi mais ou menos, comecei um dia desse, o que é esse def?

Comment: @NathanSilva é utilizado para definir uma função

Comment: é igual a função em c? ou um metodo em java?

Comment: @NathanSilva a função em C, sim. O método de Java já muda conceitualmente, mas se assemelha bastante.

Comment: obrigado, vou ler sobre, me interessei sobre isso.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o print() com opções de formatação:

```
print("Id: %s, Nome: %s" % (mostrar2[0], mostrar2[1]))
```

A opção %s pode ter mais argumentos como por exemplo um tamanho mínimo: %s20

Comment: tentei isso e nao deu certo

Answer (score -5):

Crie uma lista que receba informações de n alunos como, matrícula, nome, sobrenome, data de nascimento, cpf e e-mail. Salve essas informações em uma lista e organize por ordem alfabética